# What are the problems I can get when I port my GTK+ application to MeeGo?

Tags: qt, gtk, meego

Does MeeGo (ver 1.1 and in future 1.2) support GTK+ framework? And what are the problems I can get when I port my GTK+ application to MeeGo?

Comment: You're switching to better technology so no problems ahead! :)

Comment: If I right understand you, it was joke...

Comment: you won't have any device to run your application on

Comment: @G-71 Not really. Just read threads comparing the two on SO and you'll see most people say Qt is superior.

Comment: That's mostly a personal point of view. In the end it depends on personal preference.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: your comment is completely irrelevant... He wants to use GTK+ on Meego, not switch to Qt...

Comment: @liberforce As you noticed *Qt is encouraged for new applications* so the best thing he can do is to not swim upstream and port his app to Qt. Instead you're giving him a straw and hope he clutches it firmly :)

Comment: "what are the problems I can get when I port my GTK+ application to MeeGo?" means he most likely has already written his application, not that he is writing one from scratch... Of course for a new application, he should use Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Qt is encouraged for new applications, but GTK+ is handled (at least on Meego running on netbooks).

http://lists.meego.com/pipermail/meego-dev/2010-May/002704.html

http://wiki.meego.com/MeeGo_Netbook_and_GTK

The best for you would be to ask directly on the [meego-dev mailing list](http://lists.meego.com/listinfo/meego-dev), after having searched a recent information about that on the [archives](http://lists.meego.com/pipermail/meego-dev/) of their mailing list..

Answer (score 2):

There are things in MeeGo that support GTK+ development, like clutter and WebKit-gtk, but GTK+ was largely deprecated when Nokia joined.

Now that Nokia has left active development of MeeGo, or at least is preparing to scale back its participation and has sold certain parts of Qt, you might imagine that GTK+ would see more interest inside MeeGo. That may or may not happen, QML is considered a "hot" technology and is being used for some of interfaces in the different MeeGo verticals.

It remains to be seen if the GTK+ support will diminish or be removed entirely, it is something you certainly want to consider if you are starting a new project on MeeGo and you are bound to GTK+, you'll want to do a little data mining in the repos to see if your dependencies will be met.

Comment: What about hildon? I mean porting Maemo application based on gtk and hildon.

Comment: Hildon is also largely deprecated. It essentially was an embedded port of GTK+ but there was little interest in the GNOME community and when Nokia moved to Qt hildon was sidelined.